# Can some one help me solving this problem to install nodemon

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

```
loadDep:fsevents -> reque - |##########---------------------------------------|
WARN engine fsevents@2.3.2: wanted: {"node":"^8.16.0 || ^10.6.0 || >=11.0.0"} (c/home/gapvak-cs3/.npm-global/bin/nodemon -> /home/gapvak-cs3/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js

> nodemon@2.0.12 postinstall /home/gapvak-cs3/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
 > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate

/home/gapvak-cs3/.npm-global/lib
`-- nodemon@2.0.12 

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /nodemon/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@2.3.2
```

Comment: `Not compatible with your operating system or architecture`

Comment: `fsevents - Native access to MacOS FSEvents in Node.js` but you're on windows.

Comment: Its a warning, not a error. What does `nodemon -v` display? If you get a version number, you are fine. Most errors can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

it is just a warning on OSx, you can force installation with

```
npm install -f
```